# how to abstract invocation of method

Tags: c#, architecture, abstraction

I have a List of Tasks that a user can preform. Each one will take some time so they should be running on a background thread and reporting their progress to the UI thread.

My problem is how to achieve this in an somehow abstract way (without a big switch).

What I have now is the class Task

```
public class Task {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ??? Action { get; set; } // Doesn't compile
}
```

A ListBox with all the tasks that will draw a UserControl representing the Task (TaskUC) on SelectionChanged. This UserControl has an Execute Event ( `TaskUC.Execute += TaskExecute` ) that triggers when a user wants to Execute the task.

My problem is here. On the TaskExecute method I want to initialize a BackgroundWorker where the DoWork Handler should be defined in the Task.Action. Something like this:

```
private void TaskExecute(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Task task = (Task) e.OriginalSource;

    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkerRunWorkerCompleted;
    worker.DoWork += task.Action; // Doesn't compile

    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

And on the same class that handles the TaskExecute have the methods to handle each task.

```
private void Task1(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {}
```

So in case the user choose the first task, I need to map Task.Action to Task1 method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DoWork` event is a `DoWorkEventHandler`.
To add a delegate to this event, it must be of type `DoWorkEventHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to **not reinventing** `Task`. Use `Task<T>` which encapsulates all what you are looking for.

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx).

---

But for an answer, SLaks answer is correct.

Comment: didn't knew the Task class and I'll gonna have a look at it. But in fact SLaks answer works like a charm. Thanks for the tip though